# localhost:port_number/em (what is my port number)?

Tags: oracle-11g

I am new to SQL databases. I have started learning SQL databases from [SQLZOO](http://sqlzoo.net/), where they told me to use Oracle. I have installed Oracle Database 11g on Windows 10 with the help of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NLsJQCvKXY).
I have created a table using SQL*Plus, so I am assuming that I have installed Oracle correctly.

Now when I am trying to go to `http://localhost:1158/em` from my Google Chrome, it is saying:

> The site cannot be reached

I have searched and found that this `1158` is supposed to be my port number. I have tried many ways to find this port number for the last 3 days to no avail.

Now what should I do?
Have I missed installing something?

Comment: On Windows, `netstat -an | findstr LISTEN` will give you a list of ports that have a process listening on them. Have you installed oracle XE, or the full-blown version?

Comment: I have used Oracle 11g. I am really not sure if I have downloaded the full-blown version.

Answer (score 1):

the default port for 11g OEM is 1158. If it's not set to the default in your installation, then the value will be in portlist.ini. You can also find the full URL in the emd.properties file:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e10897/em_manage.htm#BABHJAGE

> In your Web browser, enter the following URL:
>
> https://hostname:portnumber/em
>   For example, if you installed the database on a host computer named comp42.example.com, and the installer indicated that your Enterprise Manager Console HTTP port number is 1158, then enter the following URL:
>
> https://comp42.example.com:1158/em
>   If you have recently installed Oracle Database, you can determine the port number for Database Control on Linux and UNIX systems by viewing the $ORACLE_HOME/install/portlist.ini file.
>
> Otherwise, you can determine the port number for Database Control by searching for REPOSITORY_URL in the $ORACLE_HOME/Oracle_sid/sysman/config/emd.properties file, where Oracle_sid is the system identifier (SID) for your database instance.

$ORACLE_HOME is the home directory you chose when installing the database.